# How to detect pagelinks in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I want to be able to detect when there's a page link in the URL. For example:

`www.example.com/about#link1`

I want to be able to get the `link1` parameter. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I know how to parse normal url parameters however don't know how to detect this. And there's a specific reason I want to do this..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.hash` ?

Comment: Ahh thanks sorry I didn't see this question